# How to copy & paste text from sourcefile to new file(only the nums)?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, terminal

I need your help please,
I want to copy only the nums in `source file` to `new file`(terminal code).
the `source file` look like this:

```
<name> <family> <ID>
john mark 323243434
kelly johnson 434343466
..
..
..
```

& I want to copy only the ID numbers to a new.txt file.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '$0=$3' file > newfile
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "<name> <family> <ID>
john mark 323243434
kelly johnson 434343466"|awk '$0=$3'
<ID>
323243434
434343466
```

**EDIT** with `cut`

anyway, you want fish, here it is:

```
kent$   echo "<name> <family> <ID>
john mark 323243434
kelly johnson 434343466"|cut -d' ' -f3
<ID>
323243434
434343466
```

Comment: Thank you, now I noticed that the requirement is to use the command: "cat".
yo can help me again, sorry..

Comment: no you don't need `cat`. just try the first line of my answer. then check the newfile, if it is what you want.

Comment: Your answer did help me.
But I need in my work to answer problem by choosing 'cut' command, to meet this function.

Comment: is it homework? if it is homework, we should NOT give solution directly. you can `man cut`, and do some tests. You will find the answer.

Comment: its not HW! its my work, I make summary of linux code, and I need this to my works.
I try many test and nothing.
thanks/

Comment: I am typing: $cut -d' ' -f3 source.txt > new.txt
& its didn't work.

Comment: @ItayAveksis you sure it is not separated by `<tab>`?, if it is `<tab>` you need `-d'\t'`